# How to solve ioctl operation not permitted?

Tags: android, c, kernel, ioctl, tun

I want to open a virtual interface tun, but when I use the function ioctl (ioctl(fd,TUNSETIFF,&ifr)), it always returns *ioctl operation not permitted*.

In case 1, ioctl is pass (it uses fd-socket, ioctl-SIOCGIFFLAGS):

```
jint fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "MYPROG", "fd = %d, %s", fd, strerror(errno));


memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
ifr.ifr_flags = IFF_TUN | IFF_NO_PI;

char tunnel[] = "tun";
strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, tunnel, IFNAMSIZ);

if (ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFFLAGS, (void *)&ifr)<0) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "MYPROG", "errno = %d, %s", errno, strerror(errno));
    close(fd);
    exit(1);
}

return fd;
```

it show
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hris0.jpg

But in case2, ioctl returns -1 (*operation not permitted*) (it uses fd-open, ioctl-TUNSETIFF).

```
jint fd = open("/dev/net/tun", O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK);
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "MYPROG", "fd = %d, %s", fd, strerror(errno));

memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
ifr.ifr_flags = IFF_TUN | IFF_NO_PI;

char tunnel[]="tun";
strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, tunnel, IFNAMSIZ);

if (ioctl(fd,TUNSETIFF, (void *)&ifr)<0) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "MYPROG", "errno = %d, %s", errno, strerror(errno));
    close(fd);
    exit(1);
}

return fd;
```

It shows

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ehOB.jpg

How do I pass `ioctl` in case 2?

Comment: From exactly what do you conclude `ioctl()` fails with `EPERM` (*Operation not permitted*)? `-1` just tells you that the call failed, but not for which reason.

Comment: And are you sure `open()` succeeded, that is did not return `-1`?

Comment: I use __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "MYPROG", "errnofd = %d, %s", errno, strerror(errno));

Comment: The code you show doesn't. Please **always** show real code.

Comment: Please show us where exactly you place the logging statement. This might be important.

Comment: And btw, what is this `strcpy("tun", ifr.ifr_name);` for?

Comment: Ok. So what error-message do you get when putting the log-statement **before** the call to `close()`?

Comment: I get a fd number-success, but ioctl-operation not permitted.